# Copy constructor not deep copying, error returning with array empty

Tags: c++, constructor, copy

I am doing a project for school and it requires a copy constructor, destructor, etc. When I use the copy constructor an error is thrown saying the array is empty, I assume the copy constructor is not working.

When I delete the copy constructor the program works, meaning the issue is probably happening within that function.

```
template<class T>
class DynArray {
public:

DynArray<T>(){
 ptr = new T[Capacity];
 this->Capacity = 2;
 this->Size = 0;  
}

DynArray<T>(T n) {
 ptr = new T[Capacity];
 this->Capacity = n;
 this->Size = 0;
}

DynArray<T>(const DynArray& orig) {
 cout << "Copy" << endl;
 ptr = new T[Size];
 *ptr = *(orig.ptr);
}

DynArray<T>& operator=(const DynArray<T>& orig) {
 if(this != &orig) {
 delete[] ptr;
 ptr = new T[Size];
 *ptr = *(orig.ptr);
}
return *this;  
}

void push_back(const T& n) {
 if (Size >= Capacity) {
 adjust(Capacity * 2);
 }
 ptr[Size] = n;
 Size++;
} 

void adjust(T a) {
 cout << "grow" << endl;
 T* arr = new T[a];
 for (int i = 0; i < Capacity; ++i) {
 arr[i] = ptr[i];
}
Capacity = a;
ptr = arr;
}

T& back() {
 if(Size == 0) {
 throw runtime_error("Array is empty");  
}
return ptr[Size - 1];
}

T& front() {
 if(Size == 0) {
 throw runtime_error("Array is empty");  
}
return ptr[0];
}

private:
 T* ptr = nullptr;
 int Capacity;
 int Size;
```

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dynarray.h"
using namespace std;

int main( )
{
const char START = 'A';
const int MAX = 12;

// create a vector of chars
DynArray<char> vectD;

// push some values into the vector
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
    vectD.push_back(START + i);
}

// remove the last element
vectD.pop_back();

// add another value
vectD.push_back('Z');

// test memory management
DynArray<char> vectD2 = vectD;
// display the contents
cout << "\n[";
for (int i = 0; i < vectD2.size() - 1; i++)
{
    cout << vectD2.at(i) << ", ";
}

cout << "..., " << vectD2.back() << "]\n";

DynArray<char> vectD3;
vectD3 = vectD2;
cout << "\n[";
for (int i = 0; i < vectD3.size() - 1; i++)
{
    cout << vectD3.at(i) << ", ";
}
cout << "..., " << vectD3.back() << "]\n";

vectD3.front() = '{';
vectD3.back() = '}';
cout << vectD3.front();
for (int i = 1; i < vectD3.size() - 2; i++)
{
    cout << vectD3.at(i) << ", ";
}
cout << vectD3.at(vectD3.size()-2) << vectD3.back() << endl;
}
```

Later in my code I have it set to throw a runtime_error if Size == 0, it does throw the error meaning that the array is empty. Is the copy constructor copying correctly? Main cannot be changed, it is a given from the prof.

**UPDATE**: I changed the copy constructor to copy all of the elements of the array, but the runtime_error is still returning saying the array is empty.

```
template<class T>
class DynArray {
public:

DynArray<T>(){
 ptr = new T[Capacity];
 this->Capacity = 2;
 this->Size = 0;  
}

DynArray<T>(T n) {
 ptr = new T[Capacity];
 this->Capacity = n;
 this->Size = 0;
}

DynArray<T>(const DynArray& orig) {
 cout << "Copy" << endl;
 ptr = new T[Size];
 for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
 ptr[i] = orig.ptr[i];
}
}

DynArray<T>& operator=(const DynArray<T>& orig) {
 if(this != &orig) {
 delete[] ptr;
 ptr = new T[Size];
 for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
 ptr[i] = orig.ptr[i];
}
}
return *this;  
}

void push_back(const T& n) {
 if (Size >= Capacity) {
 adjust(Capacity * 2);
 }
 ptr[Size] = n;
 Size++;
} 

void adjust(T a) {
 cout << "grow" << endl;
 T* arr = new T[a];
 for (int i = 0; i < Capacity; ++i) {
 arr[i] = ptr[i];
}
Capacity = a;
ptr = arr;
}

T& back() {
 if(Size == 0) {
 throw runtime_error("Array is empty");  
}
return ptr[Size - 1];
}

T& front() {
 if(Size == 0) {
 throw runtime_error("Array is empty");  
}
return ptr[0];
}

private:
 T* ptr = nullptr;
 int Capacity;
 int Size;
```

Comment: `*ptr` is just the first element of the array, not the actual array. C arrays do not have value semantics and can't be copied by assignment anyway.

Comment: You may study the available implementations of `std::vector` before _reinventing the wheel_.

Comment: What is `Size`?  It appears you are using its value in the copy constructor and copy assignment operator without copying the value from the source object.

Comment: private:
 T* ptr = nullptr;
 int Capacity;
 int Size;

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the definition of `DynArray` in your question, as it is essential to giving an accurate answer.

Comment: @Frettsie your edit altered the semantics of the original question, invalidating Paul's answer.  I have rolled back your edit and applied it another way.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few mistakes in your class.

The default constructor uses `Capacity` to allocate the array, before `Capacity` has been initialized.

Your reserving constructor is declared wrong.  Its input parameter should be an `int` instead of a `T`.  And it suffers from the same `Capacity` error as your default constructor.

Your copy constructor suffers from the same initialization error as well, only with `Size` instead.  And it does not perform a deep copy at all.  It is merely copying the `ptr` pointer from one class instance to another without regard to what is being pointed to.  Same with your copy assignment operator.

Your `adjust()` method is also declared wrong, and it is leaking memory.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

template<class T>
class DynArray
{
public:

  DynArray(int n = 2)
    : ptr(new T[n]), Capacity(n), Size(0)
  {
  }

  DynArray(const DynArray& orig)
    : DynArray(orig.Size)
  {
    std::cout << "Copy" << std::endl;
    std::copy(orig.ptr, orig.ptr + orig.Size, ptr);
    Size = orig.Size;
  }

  DynArray(DynArray&& orig)
    : ptr(nullptr), Size(0), Capacity(0)
  {
    orig.swap(*this);
  }

  ~DynArray()
  {
    delete[] ptr;
  }

  DynArray& operator=(const DynArray& orig)
  {
    if (this != &orig) {
      DynArray(orig).swap(*this);
    }
    return *this;  
  }

  DynArray& operator=(DynArray&& orig)
  {
    DynArray(std::move(orig)).swap(*this);
    return *this;  
  }

  void swap(DynArray &other)
  {
    std::swap(other.ptr, ptr);
    std::swap(other.Capacity, Capacity);
    std::swap(other.Size, Size);
  }

  void push_back(const T& n)
  {
    if (Size >= Capacity) {
      grow();
    }
    ptr[Size] = n;
    ++Size;
  } 

  void pop_back()
  {
    if (Size <= 0) {
      throw std::runtime_error("Array is empty");  
    }
    ptr[Size - 1] = T();
    --Size;
  }

  T& front()
  {
    if (Size <= 0) {
      throw std::runtime_error("Array is empty");  
    }
    return ptr[0];
  }

  T& back()
  {
    if (Size <= 0) {
     throw std::runtime_error("Array is empty");  
    }
    return ptr[Size - 1];
  }

  T& at(int i)
  {
    if ((i < 0) || (i >= Size)) {
      throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
    }
    return ptr[i];
  }

  T& operator[](int i)
  {
    return ptr[i];
  }

  int size() const {
    return Size;
  }

  int capacity() const {
    return Capacity;
  }

private:
  T* ptr = nullptr;
  int Capacity = 0;
  int Size = 0;

  void grow()
  {
    std::cout << "grow" << std::endl;
    DynArray newArr(Capacity * 2);
    std::copy(ptr, ptr + Size, newArr.ptr);
    newArr.Size = Size;
    newArr.swap(*this);
  }
};
```

Then, you should consider throwing all of this away and just use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead, which handles all of these details for you:

```
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class DynArray
{
public:

  DynArray(int n = 2)
  {
    vec.reserve(n);
  }

  void push_back(const T& n)
  {
    vec.push_back(n);
  } 

  void pop_back()
  {
    vec.pop_back();
  }

  T& front()
  {
    return vec.front();
  }

  T& back()
  {
    return vec.back();
  }

  T& at(int i)
  {
    return vec.at(i);
  }

  T& operator[](int i)
  {
    return vec[i];
  }

  int size() const {
    return vec.size();
  }

  int capacity() const {
    return vec.capacity();
  }

private:
  std::vector<T> vec;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your copy constructor,

```
DynArray<T>(const DynArray& orig) {
 cout << "Copy" << endl;
 ptr = new T[Size];
 *ptr = *(orig.ptr);
}
```

does not perform a deep copy.

A pointer, such as your `ptr`, is just an index to a resource (some memory block).  If you copy it, the memory block is still the same and unique, you just have copied its address.

In order to perform a deep copy, you need to allocate a new block of memory (which you do), and then copy it. To copy a block of memory means to copy each of its elements. Here, you copy only the first. Therefore,

```
DynArray<T>(const DynArray& orig) {
 cout << "Copy" << endl;
 ptr = new T[Size];
 for (size_t i = 0; i < Size, i++)
     ptr[i] = orig.ptr[i];
}
```

Note that `a[i]` is the same as `*(a+i)`, which means "the thing at the i'th position in the memory block".

Even better, you can use `std::copy` to hide the details of the deep copy operation, thus replacing the for loop:

```
std::copy(std::begin(orig.ptr), std::end(orig.ptr), std::begin(ptr));
```

in C++11, or:

```
std::copy(orig.ptr, orig.ptr + Size, ptr);
```

Comment: You can't use `memcpy()` if `T` is not trivially copyable (ie, if it has user-defined constructors). You should take that suggestion out of your answer. You can safely replace the entire `for` loop with `std::copy()` always, as it works with non trivially copyable types, and may get optimized to a `memcpy()` for trivially copyable types.